# Error Updating an item on DynamoDb (local)

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb

I have this UpdateItem method. I wanted to update a user(item)'s "city" value.

```
    var params = {
    TableName: 'Users',
    Key: { 
        id: 1,
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #ct :val', 

    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#ct': 'city'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':val': 'NewYork'
    },
};

docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

When this code snippet works, I get the error below:

```
"message":"Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: \":val\", near: \"#ct:val\""
"code":"ValidationException"
"statusCode":400
"retryable":false
```

I couldn't figure out the problem. I tried changing the quotes etc. And there is not much information and samples about these new technologies. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the "=" in the set, change it to:

```
UpdateExpression: 'SET #ct = :val',
```